# Multipe button in mvc form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC razor and I have two buttons. One is search and other one is edit button in web grid(mvc) , but there is problem problem when I click the edit button it again goes to search controller. edit button functionality i am doing with the help of JavaScript.

controller post

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Home(ManageDataViewModel vmodel)
    {
        ManageDataViewModel model = new ManageDataViewModel();
        model.SearchData(vmodel);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Please Resolve asap.

Comment: can you show your View code

Comment: Your edit button type is submit . Type should be button for edit button

Comment: i got the answers stopped search functionality using jquery prevent.default()]